# Ubuntu Server 16 Internet (Ethernet) not working

Tags: networking, server, ethernet

Disclaimer: I'm totally new to Ubuntu.

I haven't been able to figure this out, and I've looked through a lot of posts online.

I have installed Ubuntu Server on a computer. The system seems unable to connect to the internet.

The /etc/network/interfaces file looks like this:

```
# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface io inet loopback
# The primary network interface
auto enp0s31f6
iface enp0s31f6 inet static
address xxx
netmask xxx
gateway xxx
dns-nameservers xxx
```

When I try to ping something ("e.g. google.com"), I get "unknown host". I can't install any packages etiher.

When I run "ethtool enp0s31f6" I get lots of stuff that pops up, including "Link detected: Yes". If I unplug the ethernet, "Link detected: No".

I hope I have given enough information. Please let me know if I should add anything else.

Thanks.

EDIT: 
I restarted the PC after making the changes to a static address and it now shows the correct IP and info when I do `ifconfig`. However, ping still doesn't work.

Comment: Does `ifconfig` confirm that the ethernet interface of interest is indeed `enp0s31f6`? You only need address, netmask, gateway and dns-nameservers. With more information, I will propose an answer.

Comment: @chili555 `ifconfig` does confirm that it is the one. I took out the unnecessary parameters.

Comment: Can you ping the gateway? How about: `ping -c3 8.8.8.8`?

Comment: @chili555 See my answer to that comment in your answer.

Comment: I am flagging this for being a bit too broad now that we have narrowed it down a bit I have been able to formulate a better question.

Answer (score 3):

If you have a DHCP Server in you network, try (as root):

$dhclient

In a Terminal/Shell. This should work.

If you need a specific configuration, you can do this like the others described in /etc/network/interfaces and /etc/resolv.conf (for the nameservers).

I think it would be a good idea, if you post your /etc/network/interfaces and /etc/resolv.conf, but maybe try dhclient first.

Answer (score 1):

See if your interface got an ip from dhcp first.

```
ifconfig -a
```

(if it doesn't have an ip try assigning one manually) Then if you got an ip then try

```
ping <gateway>
```

(if this doesn't work your network config is wrong) If that works then try pinging a public ip like 8.8.8.8. (if this works then your name resolution is not working (dns).

```
cat /etc/resolv.conf
```

and see if you have valid name servers there.

Comment: I am trying to set my IP address manually now, but it doesn`t seem to change in the ifconfig -a. It shows up as 10.0.0.10, when I have tried to set it to something else.
See my edit.

Comment: You need to `sudo ifdown enp0s31f6` and `sudo ifup  enp0s31f6` to get your new configuration to work.

Comment: @Jos After doing that, ifconfig still gives me the wrong inet addr. Should I have the line: `auto enp0s31f6` in my interfaces?

Comment: Yes. You need that one, but you don't need the `network` and `broadcast` statements. Take these out and try again. Also `address` has a double d, perhaps that's where your problem is.

Comment: @Jos `network` and `broadcast` are gone now. The `address` was a typo in the question, but it is spelt correctly in the file. Still no luck.

Answer (score 1):

Your interfaces file need only contain:

```
# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface io inet loopback
# The primary network interface
auto enp0s31f6
iface enp0s31f6 inet static
address xxx
netmask xxx
gateway xxx
dns-nameservers xxx
```

Please note that you said 'adress' and it should be address. Be sure to select an address *outside* the range used in the router, switch or access point for DHCP.

Get the system to re-read and use the file:

```
sudo ifdown enp0s31f6 && sudo ifup enp0s31f6
```

Check:

```
ifconfig

ping -c3 www.ubuntu.com
```

Comment: My interfaces file now matches yours. The `ping` still does not work (unknown host).

Comment: Can you ping the gateway? How about: `ping -c3 8.8.8.8`?

Comment: When I `ping -c3 8.8.8.8` it appears to work (3 packages transmitted, 3 received). Pinging the gateway does not work. Does this mean I have the wrong gateway info?

Comment: Probably; and maybe the wrong DNS. Are your settings consistent with the gateway, DNS, etc., for other devices on the same network? Phones, desktop, 'Pads, 'Pods, etc.?

Comment: It's identical (apart from address) to the settings on a PC connected to the same network. The settings say TCP/IPv4 though.

Comment: When you are pinging the gateway, may I assume it is: `ping -c3 192.168.1.1` or some such? Are the DNS nameservers the same as well?

Comment: Yes, it is like that. One of the DNS nameservers is the same as the gateway. Do I have to add anything to the /etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/base file?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42056/discussion-between-sastreen-and-chili555).